# Tabs not showing Tablayout + ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

The tab contents are rendered I can swipe between them but the tabs are not showing.
[image]

activity_home.xml (Note how I nest TabLayout under ViewPager as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:elevation="2dp" />
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declaring Your View and Variables

    Toolbar mToolbar;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;
    TabLayout mSlidingTabs;
    CharSequence mTabTitles[] = {"Home", "Events"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        initSlidingTabs();
    }

    private void initSlidingTabs() {
        mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mTabTitles);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the mViewPagerAdapter
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
```

//        // Also tried the following but nothing changes
//        mSlidingTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
//        mSlidingTabs.addTab(mSlidingTabs.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
//        mSlidingTabs.addTab(mSlidingTabs.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
//        mSlidingTabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        }
    }

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence mTabTitles[]; // This will Store the mTabTitles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created

    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[]) {
        super(fm);

        this.mTabTitles = mTitles;
    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        }
        else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        }
    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTabTitles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabTitles.length;
    }
}
```

Tab1.java

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Using a TabLayout inside a ViewPager like it's documented, but I don't see tabs. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue right this very moment.

Following Google's documentation by nesting a `TabLayout` inside the `ViewPager` does **not** work.

Following Google's documentation by nesting a `PagerTabStrip` inside the `ViewPager` **does** work.

---

### Solution

Do **NOT** nest the `TabLayout` inside the `ViewPager`.  Place it immediately adjacent to the `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you placing the TabLayout inside the ViewPager?.
You also need to call tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

Comment: Hi @AmmarMohammed, 1) I'm putting `TabLayout` inside `ViewPager` because the documentation said so (link in my question) 2) Yes, I've tried that, nothing changed as mentioned in my question

Comment: Try to put the TabLayout under the Toolbar within an AppBarLayout, I used the exact same structure and it worked for me.

Comment: but why? @AmmarMohammed, that sounds like a hack to me. Are you saying Google's documentation is wrong here?

Comment: Just try it, I haven't read the docs to be honest but I am following some tutorial as far as I remember.

Comment: Please see this: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: I have seen it work with the TabLayout inside the ViewPager - my guess would be that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:elevation="2dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but you are putting the `TabLayout` outside of the `ViewPager` which defeats the purpose of my question

Answer (score 0):

If a View implements Decor, then ViewPager treats it as a special View that can remain on top of it the ViewPager.  This is normally for implementing your own tabs.

For more information go through this links:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

> This view also supports being used as part of a ViewPager's decor, and
>   can be added directly to the ViewPager in a layout resource

For decor:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

> Views which are annotated with the ViewPager.DecorView annotation are
>   treated as part of the view pagers 'decor'. Each decor view's position
>   can be controlled via its android:layout_gravity attribute

I think for better understanding, you can through this [blog](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2013/11/sample-android-project-movies.html).

**Final Conclusion:**

You have to implement

> From interface java.lang.annotation.Annotation